# Apify: PseudoUrl regex to match urls containing a given keyword

Tags: regex, apify

Apify [PseudoUrl](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/pseudourl) supports  JavaScript-style regular expression to match against the URL.

I tried following RegEx to match all the urls that contains a particular keyword -

```
//not working
http://www.example.com/[*foo*]
```

So for example, if a website has following links:

```
http://www.example.com/pages/
http://www.example.com/pages/bar

http://www.example.com/pages/foo/bar.html
http://www.example.com/pages/test-foo-test.html
http://www.example.com/pages/foo.html
```

The regex should match last 3 urls. However, the regex is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also pass a regular javascript regex to the `PseudoUrl` constructor.

You would want a regex of the form `^http:\/\/www.example.com\/pages\/.*foo`.

Assuming you want to do this for multiple keywords, you could use something like this:

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const regexEscape = require('regex-escape');

function createKeywordUrlRegex(baseUrl, keyword) {
  const regexStr = `^${regexEscape(baseUrl)}.*?${regexEscape(keyword)}`;
  // remove the i if you want to match to be case-sensitive
  return new RegExp(regexStr, 'i');
}

const purl = new Apify.PseudoUrl(createKeywordUrlRegex('http://www.example.com/pages/', 'foo'));

// print out the examples
const examples = [
'http://www.example.com/pages/',
'http://www.example.com/pages/bar',
'http://www.example.com/pages/foo/bar.html',
'http://www.example.com/pages/test-foo-test.html',
'http://www.example.com/pages/foo.html'
];
for(let example of examples)
  console.log(example, purl.matches(example) ? 'MATCH!' : 'IGNORED');
```

You can pass a base url like `http://www.example.com/pages/` and a keyword like `foo` to `createKeywordUrlRegex` and it will generate the regex mentioned above for you.

Comment: you are awesome!!! thanks so much for your answer. I wasted so much time on this issue..

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for the existence of `foo` anywhere after the domain stuff:

```
http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/.*foo
```

https://regex101.com/r/UlSb4w/2

Comment: you could also use `http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/.*foo`, without a lookahead